I've bountied my 4.7 year old Astronomy SE question three times and still no answer. In this particular case, is it OK to post it here also?
Near-simultaneous cross-posting is always bad. The primary concern is answer fragmentation.
Generally, flagging for moderator assistance to migrate is the way to go for questions that are less than three months old.
After three months though, migration is no longer possible.
I asked Why does titanium oxide around Betelgeuse produce this particular sawtooth-shaped absorption spectrum? in Astronomy SE in March of 2020, which is currently 4.7 years ago, and I've bountied it three times, and bumped it a few more, but still no answer.
In this kind of situation, generally reposting to an alternative and relatively suitable site is considered OK by many sites/many users, but not all of them.
How do you folks feel about posting it here in Chemistry SE?
Because of the comments and bounty history I will not be deleting it there, but if an answer does appear here one can also give a brief summary in an answer post there and link to the more thorough answer here. That's usually how I've seen it done.

Snipped of the question for your viewing pleasure:

Question: The images below show absorption features assigned to titanium oxide (TiO) around Betelgeuse. Why are these features saw-tooth shaped? When I think of absorption edges the transmitted light drops when crossing from lower to higher energy photons, but here the measured light increases from lower to higher energy.
note 1: A quick check shows that these shapes are typical, so it's really just a matter of me not understanding why these features have the particular shapes that they do.
note 2: There is some discussion of Betelgeuse's titanium lines in the second half of Scott Manley's Astronomers Think They Know Why Betelgeuse Got Dimmer


Fig. 1.— Optical spectrophotometry of Betelgeuse from 2020 (black) and 2004 (red).



Fig. 2.— Normalized and continuum-flattened spectra of Betelgeuse from 2020 (black) and 2004 (red dashed), illustrating the relative depths of the Teff-sensitive TiO bands (labeled) in both spectra.




Not every question can have an answer. 2. Not every question can be on topic here. You have to check if that question has any chemistry aspect in order to post here.


I think it's appropriate here (but perhaps better suited  for physics SE?)

@BuckThorn atomic spectral features are certainly on topic in Physics SE. However I avoid Physics SE like the plague. It's much better than it used to be, but there is still in my opinion a strong sense that if the first viewers don't think they can answer a question, they feel it's the question's fault and therefore it should be closed. Or if I'm lucky, it's ignored and roombad in six months. They like questions that allow them to "sound smart" and write long "scholarly" answers. I call them "Why is there momentum?" questions. To me it's the most disappointing SE site.

I have a hunch that these shapes have something to do with temperature and population of rotational/vibrational states (the slope down to higher energy) and that's the kind of thing (at least some) Chemists like to think about.

I think this is about instrumentation, interferences, and massaging data. Perhaps about what happens to the light since leaving a distant star (400 years ago?) and arriving on Earth. // @EdV https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/users/79678/ed-v for instance can probably provide some help if he's around.

I don’t know the cause of the sawtooth shape of the TiO bands. I think other species, such as ZrO and HfO also show this behavior. Maybe Gerhard Herzberg’s book (I do not have a copy) might discuss this: Molecular Spectra and Molecular Structure: I. Spectra of Diatomic Molecules. (Krieger, 1989). It should be in any good university library. I am wondering if SiO also shows this behavior. I will do some searching and update if I find anything possibly useful.

@BuckThorn Oddly enough, my first scientific publication was back in 1980, in Reviews of Scientific Instrumentation, and it involved the absorbance and MCD (magnetic circular dichroism) spectra, in the visible range, of TiO that was matrix-isolated in Ar at 14 K. But the absorbance spectrum we measured shows no sawtooth aspects. There has to be an extensive literature on TiO spectra, but I am not familiar with it. Anyway, I will keep looking.

@EdV I'll have a copy in front of me in an hour. Thanks! (and that's interesting about your TiO work, and consistent with this being related to temperature)

@EdV My hunch was that the lineshape was dispersive (which might help with resolving peak maxima in noisy spectra) but after quickly browsing I don't understand much more about how such optical spectra are acquired or handled. I'd guess you would. I don't know how TiO is relevant in general but assume it is a well understood reference system?

@BuckThorn Your assumption is correct: TiO is a pretty well understood reference system, just not by me, unfortunately! Acquiring low resolution stellar spectra is not hard nowadays: lots of amateur “astro spectroscopists” do this and even acquire spectra of comets. I am a lurking member of an astro spectroscopy group and enjoy seeing what talented users post there. Unfortunately for me, my sky is very light polluted and I do not have a good telescope with good tracking. If I had the scope, all I would need, for a basic setup, would be a 100 or 200 lines/mm transmission grating, an astro

camera (mono, not color) and RSpec software to process the acquired spectra. It is even possible to just use a DSLR camera with the grating and RSpec software. I have that gear, but the bad sky is still the big problem. Going somewhere darker is an option, except we have critters in the night: bears and coyotes. And skunks.

Not sure if this link will work, but it goes to Tim Stone’s Betelgeuse spectra at various resolutions, showing the sawteeth spectra: https://rspec-astronomy.groups.io/g/main/topic/89378390#msg11429.

@EdV It would be tempting to take that plunge and start looking at the skies but I have similar obstacles, however no problem with interferences from coyotes or bears, perhaps moose, or wolves if very lucky or unlucky. With your inspiration I might yet look into a basic setup. By tracking I suppose you mean a motorized telescope?

@BuckThorn Yes, tracking means motorized in one of the various ways telescope tracking can be done, e.g., equatorial or alt-az, etc. One of my good friends, an emeritus UMass professor like me, has been doing astrophotography for several years and he is getting wonderful images, which he shares with me. Most recently, I went to his place (he has dark sky) and we saw the comet. He is also now adept at image processing. I get a vicarious pleasure out of all his shared work. Also, about the moose: I have a small house on 0.2 acres, but we had an adult female moose in our tiny back yard years ago!
